# If the validation of textbox fails it should be in same textbox and restrict user to move to another textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In the below code i have a javascript function and a textbox.The validations are working perfectly.My aim if the validation fails it should clear the textbox value and cursor should be in the same textbox it should not move to other controls.

JS:

```
function ValidateRegExp(txtInput, REGEXP) {
    var mySplitResult = new Array();
    mySplitResult = REGEXP.split("~~");

    var iReturn = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length - 1; i++) {

        var re = new RegExp(mySplitResult[i]);
        if (!txtInput.match(re)) {
            iReturn = iReturn + 1;
        }
    }

    if (iReturn > 0) {
        alert("Failed...");
    } else {
        alert("Success...");
    }

}
```

codebehind:

```
 txtField.Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:ValidateRegExp(document.getElementById('" + txtField.ClientID + "').value, '" + hidRegExp.Value + "');");
```

Comment: it's good to know you have a goal...but do you have a question?

Comment: @ Leo if the validation fails the cursor should be in same textbox the user should be restricted to move to other controls(User cannot able to leave the textbox if it is failure)

Comment: Have you tried this `document.getElementById("txtField").focus();`

Comment: @ Dotnet yes i tried but focus is not set on textbox

Comment: `focus()` doesn’t work, because you’ve not yet left the `textbox`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it is not working for me this works I have just created a simple example by taking 2 textboxes

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtField" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
</form>
```

and this is my script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        var txt = document.getElementById("txtField");
        if (txt.value === "" || txt.value.length <= 1) {
            txt.value = ''; // to clear the textbox value
            txt.focus(); // focus on the textbox
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is in `aspx.cs` file

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  txtField.Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:validate()");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

On Leave event or the blur even of every control you can call the validate() function. There is a property that focuses on invalid input. so it will stuck to the textbox till the valid data is put.

http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/